# SAPUI5 : OPA5 and Qunit Testing - how to write, place and arrange my specs?

Tags: automated-tests, sapui5, qunit

I would like to know what would be a good way to write, place and arrange my specs for a SAPUI5 application.

Browsing the SDK, I see some short Qunit and OPA5 examples and snippets. What I faild to understand is where I should place those specs. Which Folders, where to put assertions, where to put matchers, what goes into .js files and what goes into .html files.

I have a Ruby on Rails history and was used to put everything into their conventional test/.. folderts and to start all specs an once from a console line.

How can I get something similar (well arranged and written specs) for SAPUI5 Projects?

Answer (score 0):

Create a QUnit test page `myqunittest.qunit.html` in the folder `test-resources/.`

All steps are explained in this link - [Unit Testing with QUnit](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/09d145cd86ee4f8e9d08715f1b364c51)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not happy with this answer. I have read the linked page before asking my question and found it to be very superficial.

Comment: also, the link does not exist

Comment: And if something is missing in documentation, I can explain.. I am not sure why it looks superficial..